# Where can I view the figures from a patent?

Tags: google-patents, patent-figures, wo2004085005

I was just really wondering if there was a picture I could view for the invention in [WO2004085005A3](https://google.com/patents/WO2004085005A3)?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking at the google patents page, there is a link at the bottom of the gray box "External Links: Patentscope, Espacenet". Either can lead you to the documents published in the case.

[image]

Comment: I agree, this gets closer to the figures, but a new user may have difficulty finding them on the site. The original application contains some hand-drawn figures and can be downloaded from the [Documents](https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/detail.jsf?docId=WO2004085005&recNum=1&tab=PCTDocuments) page as a [PDF](https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/docservicepdf_pct/id00000001570063/PDOC/WO2004085005.pdf), and the figures from the WIPO application can be found on the [Drawings](https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/detail.jsf?docId=WO2004085005&recNum=1&tab=Drawings) page.

Answer (score 0):

You can look up all the documents for the patent and patent application (including drawings) by going to the US PTO website and looking for the Public PAIR webpage.

http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair

Then enter the patent application number or patent number.